# Play continuous music when swapping between multiple scenes

Tags: unity, c#, music

I have the following scenario

1. "Main menu" scene containing a game object with an audio source component and a music manager script.
2. An "about us" scene

Music manager script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class ManageMusic : MonoBehaviour {

public static ManageMusic Instance;

void Awake()
{

    if (Instance)
        DestroyImmediate (gameObject);
    else {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
        Instance = this;

    }
  }
}
```

When I click on the "about us" button, the `Game Music object` keeps on playing and I can hear the music, but when I return back to the main menu no music is playing. I can see that the music game object is not destroyed when I return to the main menu and the audio listener has the value of the volume set to `1` , but I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Just read the tutorial page I linked you on stackoverflow and try to understand the concept, and implement the singleton as your code apparently doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DontDestroyOnLoad` for the music player. [Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) Also make sure that the music player is a singleton and is not instanciated when re-loading scenes.

[See here for details](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11314/audio-or-music-to-continue-playing-between-scene-c.html)